# Удалить те строки, вторичного ключа которых нет в другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Пробую

```
DELETE FROM `locality_text` WHERE locality_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM `locality`)
```

Таблица locality

```
id | parent_id
1  |     NULL
2  |      1
```

Таблица locality_text

```
id | locality_id |
1  |     1       | Московская
2  |     2       | Москва
3  |     5       | Рыба
4  |     10      | Кит
5  |     2       | Стак
6  |     1       | Оверфлов
```

В результате искомого запроса нужно чтобы удались строки 3 и 4 locality_text

Пробный запрос удаляет всё(

Comment: Мне кажется, что всё-таки запрос верен, ошибка была в данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete t1.*
from locality_text t1
left join locality t2 on t1.locality_id = t2.id
where t2.id is null
```

или эквивалент с not exists.